# Error - PerfectScrollbar : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: typescript, angular6

This code is working fine:-

```
$(".info).scrollTop(0);
```

But, below equivalent code is displaying error:-

```
let ele : HTMLElement =  document.querySelector('.info');
 ele.scrollTop(0);  <---- Error

Error: - Error - PerfectScrollbar : Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

The first snippet uses JQuery, and the object returned by JQuery has a method named `scrollTop`.

The second snippet uses the browser DOM api which returns a `HTMLElement`. On this object `scrollTop` is number representing the scroll offset. To scroll to a specific location you must use the `scrollTo` method:

```
ele.scrollTo({
  top: 10
})
```